# Unable to set SameSite on cookies

Tags: c#, servicestack

We are setting a cookie on request:

```
var cookie = new Cookie()
{
    Path = "/",
    Name = "TestCookie",
    Value = "Value",
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
    Secure = true,
    HttpOnly = true,
};
this.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

There is no option of same site on this cookie object or an overload.

Additionally, we are already setting:

```
var hostConfig = new HostConfig
{
    ...
    UseSameSiteCookies = true,
    ...
}
```

How can we set the sameSite to strict via servicestacks method?

Comment: That should be all you need, are you using SSL?

Comment: You are indeed correct. Looks like I was conditionally setting UseSameSiteCookies  to false. When it is set to true behaves as expected